# Проверить по возрастанию ли значения в массиве?

Tags: массивы, c++

Вот есть массив со значениями (1,2,5,6...). Как проверить, идут ли эти значения в массиве по возрастанию?

Comment: @VladD увы. Ответ вне пределов моей компетенции.

О наличии haskell на ideone.com не догадывался.

Comment: @alexlz: Можно например сгенерировать в `getSequence` _огромный_ объём данных (скажем, 10 гигабайт), и посмотреть на расход памяти. Если вычисленные значения сохраняются, пиковый расход памяти будет огромен, и программа вылетит по out of memory.

Comment: @VladD это как? Принудительно (strict -- `$!` или `seq`) задать генерацию до выполнения zip? Можно, но считать список два раза программа всё равно не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

проходим в цикле весь массив и сравниваем текущий элемент (i) со следующим (i+1)

если хоть раз **`if([i] <= [i+1])`** вернёт **`false`** то значения идут не по возрастанию...

**UPD**

выше проверка на "не строгое" возрастание...

**`if([i] < [i+1])`** - "строгое" возрастание

- `1223345666`- не строгое
- `123456`- строгое

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat `<=` -- это по неубыванию. По возрастанию -- `<`. Ну и в качестве шутки:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <utility>
    int a[] = {1, 2, 4, 6};
    int main() {
        auto p = std::accumulate(a+1, a+4, std::make_pair(true, a[0]), 
                [](std::pair<bool, int> p, int x) -> std::pair<bool, int> {return std::make_pair(p.first && x > p.second, x);});
        std::cout << p.first <<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

(а пусть боятся)

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: @alexlz: на C# несколько читаемее:

    arr.Skip(1).Zip(arr, (prev, next) => prev < next).All(v => v);

---
Хотя у меня в коде обычно есть helper:

    arr.Pairwise((prev, next) => prev < next).AllTrue();

Comment: @alexlz: Это в принципе не отличается ничем от первого варианта на C#, и тоже, насколько я понимаю, дважды пробегается по последовательности. А можно на хаскеле второй вариант, с Pairwise и одним проходом?

Comment: @VladD во-первых я не вижу тут два прохода. Во-вторых, я не знаю, что такое Parwise (увы) (ссылка на msdn приветствуется). Ну а реализация с foldl -- пожалуйста:

      f (x:xs) = fst $ foldl (\(b, y') y -> (b && y' < y, y)) (True, x) xs
      f _ = True

Comment: @alexlz: `Pairwise` — это вот такая функция (не из MSDN, пишется вручную): http://ideone.com/Lap4CW

Превращает [1, 2, 5, 28] в [(1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 28)].

---
`zip` же проходится и по `x'`, и по `xs`, так что если `x'` производится генератором, тот сгенерирует каждый элемент дважды. Или хаскель умеет такое соптимизировать?

Comment: @VladD не очень понял, в чём проблема. `x'` и `xs` -- один и тот же список, только смещённый на одну позицию. Элементы списка неизменяемы (immutable). Зачем их вычислять дважды? Я не очень разбираюсь в оптимизациях ghc, но вычислять два раза одно значение программа не должна.

А pairwise -- так вот оно и есть

     pairwise x'@(x:xs) = zip x' xs
     pairwise _ = []

(не нравятся @-шаблоны, тогда

     pairwise (x:xs) = zip (x:xs) xs
     pairwise _ = []

Comment: @alexlz: смотрите, пусть у нас последовательность ленива, и генерируется «на лету». Вот этот код: http://pastebin.com/UhMcAR2D выводит у меня «`enumerating...`» дважды, то есть, все вычисления повторяются. Материализация последовательности, чтобы избежать повторного вычисления — не выход, т.к. последовательность потенциально бесконечна и имеет право не влезть в память.

Код с `Pairwise` этого недостатка не имеет.

Comment: @VladD http://pastebin.com/CDyDdv2T . Надеюсь устроит? 

    import Debug.Trace
    import Control.Monad (forM_)
    getSequence m = [(\x -> trace ("\n*" ++ show x ++ "*") x) $ sqrt $ fromInteger x' | x' <- [1.. m*m]]
    g2 (l:ls) = zip (l:ls) ls
    main = forM_ (g2 $ getSequence 2) (putStrLn . show)

Замучился с капчей, а текст влезает в комментарий. Надеюсь это адекватная трансляция?

(транслятор лежит где-то на www.haskell.org)

Comment: @alexlz: Круто, чё. Хаскель смог соптимизировать два прохода по последовательности в один без трюков. (http://ideone.com/QFODlS) Всё же интересно, как это работает внутри — запоминается вычисленная последовательность? Или сработало common subexpression elimination?